# Keeping replicas of Redis instances in sync ?

Tags: linux, redis, replication

It is possible to create repicas of a Redis instance? If yes, what is the overhead of keeping them in sync (apart from the network traffic) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/replication) on setting up replication scenarios.
Since there is a delay between synchronisation, you'll probably need additional application-side logic to keep access that uses the same data to the same server instance. In some cases you may also need to issue additional 'slaveof' commands to one instance in case another goes down/comes back up.

If you need more concrete info, you should elaborate a bit on your use case, i.e. in what environment you're using Redis (i.e. Rails app cluster, custom client...).